# I need to add the pause button for the countdown timer, I used Tkinter and when I clicked the start button but can't stop the timer

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I need to add the stop button, please help me, thanks

```
 def addTask(self):
    newTask = self.taskMaker()
    self.listOfTasks.append(newTask)
    new_entry = self.stringFormat()
    #Adding to the listbox if there is a name and some time input
    if newTask.name != "" and (newTask.hours != "0" or newTask.minutes != "0" or newTask.seconds != "0"):
        self.tasksListbox.insert(tkinter.END, new_entry)  
    #Display a warning message when above requirements havent been met
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="You must enter a task!")
#Gets all the input values from the user and makes a task object
def taskMaker(self):
    taskName = self.task.get()
    hours = self.hourInput.get()
    minutes = self.minuteInput.get()
    seconds = self.secondInput.get()
    newTask = Task(taskName, hours, minutes, seconds)
    return newTask


#Converts the hours,minutes,seconds to all seconds
def secondsConverter(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
    intHours = int(hours)
    intMinutes = int(minutes)
    intSeconds = int(seconds)
    self.converted = (intHours * 3600) + (intMinutes * 60) + intSeconds
    return self.converted 


#Loops through the list of task objects to display the count down for each one
def startTimer(self):      
    for task in self.listOfTasks:
        hours = task.getHours()
        minutes =  task.getMinutes()
        seconds =  task.getSeconds()
        convertedTime = self.secondsConverter(hours, minutes, seconds)
        self.counting(convertedTime)

def stopTimer(self):
    # if self.paused is not None:
    #    self.after_cancel(self.isRunning)
    #    print ("Waiting for")
    #    self.paused = None
    if self.paused is not None:
        self.isRunning = True
    
#Formats the task into a string to be presented in the listbox
def stringFormat(self):
    taskName= self.task.get()
    hours = self.hourInput.get()
    minutes = self.minuteInput.get()
    seconds = self.secondInput.get()
    stringconcat = "Task: " + str(taskName) + "   Hours: "+ str(hours) + "   Minutes: " + str(minutes) + "   Seconds: " + str(seconds)
    return stringconcat
# Main countdown loop function 
def counting(self, startTime):
    if self.isRunning != True:
        self.isRunning = True
        while startTime > -1:
            if startTime >= 0:
                mins,secs = divmod(startTime,60)
                tempHour = 0
                if mins>59:
                    tempHour, mins = divmod(mins,60)
            timeformat = "{0:02d}:".format(tempHour)+("{0:02d}:{1:02d}".format(mins,secs))
            app.timerLabel.configure(text=timeformat)
            startTime -= 1
            self.update()
            time.sleep(1)
        self.isRunning = False
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up!")
```

Comment: similar problem was few times on Stackoverflow.

Comment: we can't run your code so we can't see how it works. Better create minimal working code with your problem

Comment: you shouldn't use `while`-loop because it can freeze all GUI - you could use `root.after(millisecond, function_names)`

Comment: you check `isRunning` outside `while`-loop so it CAN'T stop it when you press stop. You should check `isRunning` inside `while`-loop

Comment: Change `while startTime > -1` to `while self.isRunning and startTime > -1`.